# Toggling an icon is only working for one item

Tags: javascript

I have been reading many posts about toggling an icon and I got some code to work but it only works for one item and I have 23 of them.

Basically, it's an accordion of FAQ's and when you click on it the answer shows but I want a plus and minus sign to show and toggle depending on if it's collapsed or not.

I found this code and updated with my site and it works but only for the first FAQ.

```
$("#switch").click(function(event) {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square').toggleClass('fa-minus-square');
    });
```

What do I need to do to make it so they all change?

I thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Without seeing a (representative) [mcve] sample of your HTML how would we know what's happening, without making guesses?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you can also use `.toggleClass('fa-plus-square fa-minus-square')` to toggle both classes, it's down to preference but could be considered tidier.

Answer (score 3):

Only one item on the page can have the id `switch`. Change this to a class and select using `$('.switch')` to apply the event to each item.